# Computing $\int \frac{6x}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to compute an indefinite integral. Thanks!

$$\int \frac{6x}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx.$$

Comment: Can you format it in latex/Mathjax?

Comment: @punjab: Welcome to MSE! Please use LaTex / MathJax (see FAQ). Also, please make sure I got it right.

Answer (score 6):

First, try the substitution $u=x+2$, then use an appropriate [trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution).

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\int \dfrac{6x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 8}}\, dx\;
& = \;\int \dfrac{6x+12 -12}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 8}} \,dx \\ \\ \\ \\
& = \int \dfrac {6(x + 2) - 12}{\sqrt {\color{blue}{\bf (x^2+ 4x + 4) + 4}}}\,dx 
\end{align}$$

split the integral into the difference of two integrals:

$$ = \;\int \dfrac {6(x + 2)}{\sqrt {(x^2 + 4x + 8}}\,dx\;\; -\;\; 12\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\color{blue}{\bf (x+2)^2 + 2^2}}}\, dx $$

Now, for the left hand integral,

- let $u = x^2 + 4x + 8 \implies du = 2x + 4 = 2(x + 2) \,dx,\implies\; 3du = 6(x+2)\,dx$. Substitute: you'll have an integral of the form $\;3\int u^{-1/2} \,du$

For the right-hand integral,

- let $\;v = x+2\;\implies\;dv = dx.$
- And as suggested, you'll want to use an appropriate trigonometric
  substitution for the right-hand integral: in particular, find the
  promising [hyperbolic trig substitution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution#Hyperbolic_functions)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a quadratic expression in your integral, especially in the denominator or under a square root (or, in this case, both!), you should do the following steps:

1: Complete the square. Remember that this will look like $(x + a)^2 + b$, where $a$ is equal to one half the $x$ term, and $b$ is whatever you need to add to get the constant term to match up. In your case, the $x$ term is $4x$, so $a$ should be $1/2 \cdot 4 = 2$. So you get $(x + 2)^2 + b = x^2 + 4x + 8$, and so it's easy to see that $b$ should be $4$:

$$x^2 + 4x + 8 = (x + 2)^2 + 4$$

2: Make the substitution $u = x + 2$, to clean up the quadratic expression a bit. This isn't necessary, but I find it makes it nicer, and match up with other situations more easily. Your integral becomes:

$$\int \frac{6(u -2)}{\sqrt{u^2 + 4}}du$$

3: Now you should recognize this as a problem where you should use a trig substitution. The proper substitution to make in this case is:

$$u = 2\tan(\theta)$$

$$du = 2\sec^2(\theta)$$

The reason this is so nice is because:

$$\sqrt{u^2 + 4} = \sqrt{4\tan^2(\theta) + 4} = 2\sqrt{\tan^2(\theta) + 1} = 2\sqrt{\sec^2{\theta}} = \sec(\theta)$$

And so your integral becomes:

$$\int \frac{6(\tan(\theta) - 2)(2\sec^2(\theta))}{2\sec(\theta)}d\theta$$

$$= 6\int [\tan(\theta)\sec(\theta) - 2\sec(\theta)] d\theta$$

4: You should now be able to compute this integral using standard methods for integrating trig functions. For instance, the integral of $\tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)$ is $\sec(\theta)$- you should memorize this. The integral of $\sec(\theta)$ is something more complicated, but the formula is probably given (another good thing to memorize).

5: And so, you have your formula:

$$6\sec(\theta) - 12\ln(|\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta)|) + C$$

Now you need to substitute $\theta = \tan^{-1}(u/2)$. You want to come up with a simple expression for $\sec(\tan^{-1}(u/2)$, the best way to do this is to draw a right triangle with the angle $\theta$ having a tangent of $u/2$. So the opposite leg has length $u$ and the adjacent leg has length $2$. Now, you can see that the secant of $\theta$ is $\sqrt{u^2 + 4}/2$. And so:

$$3\sqrt{u^2 + 4} - 12\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{u^2 + 4}}{2} + \frac{u}{2}\right| + C$$

Finally, plug in $u = x + 2$:

$$3\sqrt{(x + 2)^2 + 4} - 12\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{(x + 2)^2 + 4}}{2} + \frac{x + 2}{2}\right| + C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{6x}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}}dx=\int\frac{6(x+2)-12}{\sqrt{(x+2)^2+2}}dx$$
$$=6\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}dx-12\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}dx$$
$$=6\sqrt{x^2+2}-12\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x+2}{2}\right)+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{6x +12 -12}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx
  &= \int \frac{6x +12}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx - \int \frac{12}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx \\
  &= \int \frac{6(x+2)}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx - \int \frac{12}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx \\ 
  &= \int \frac{3(2x+4)}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx - \int \frac{12}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+8}} dx.
\end{align}$$

Then take 
$x^2+4x+8 = t$ substitution in 1st integral and performed perfect polynomial in second integral then simplify to get the answer.

Comment: Please take some time comparing your original monstrosity using `$$...$$ $$...$$ $$...$$` to my edit using `align`. That is "How It's Done (TM)".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Wolfram Alpha URL with the solution. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+6x+%2F+%28sqrt%28x%5E2+%2B+4x+%2B+8%29%29